# Spring security oauth2 client in kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've a requirement where I need to write an oauth2 client using spring security which is to be deployed in a kubernetes cluster. There can be a scenario where the same client is going to be deployed in a multicluster set up also.

I see documentations online where we can use spring security to write an oauth2 client. But how can we make it work in multiple pods or multipleclusters simultaneously. If one of the pod obtains an access token, how can we persist across multiple pods and clusters. I went through the documentations and I see `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` which will not be suitable when we're considering a deployment like this.

Is there any way we can write an oauth2 client with spring security, where it can be deployed in multiple pods or clusters, still gets the access token only once until it expires ? By using some kind of persistence in between these pods.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would it be a problem that each pod gets its own access-token?

Comment: I was just checking on the possibilities, once we've an active access token until it expires we should be using that right ? Once we've multiple pods and clusters, it will be getting new access tokens for each of them. Is this expected to be like that ?  or it can be optimized.? 
Just checking on those possibilities.

Comment: If a user has two mobile phones, can he login with for example Twitter on both phones? Why should that a problem for your pods? However, if you want to handle user authentication in a centralized way, you could use Spring Cloud Gateway and then route the request to the pod.

Comment: @dur Thanks for the explanation. Would checkout the possibility of using Spring Cloud Gateway.